# List a classes generic interface names

Tags: c#, interface

I have this c# code;

```
case "Cafe":
  source.trendItem = new TrendingLocation<ITrendingCafe>();
  break;
case "Pub":
  source.trendItem = new TrendingLocation<ITrendingPub>();
  break;
etc
```

a `trendItem` is defined like this;

```
public class TrendingItem<T> where T : ITrendingItem
{
    public T trendItem { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this;

```
public List<TrendingItem<ITrendingItem>> trendItems { get; set; }
```

Now for each item in the above trendItems i want to get the interfaces.

I tried using;

```
string g = fvm.trendItems[4].trendItem.GetType().GetInterfaces()[1].Name;
```

and

```
string g = typeof(TrendingLocation<>).GetInterfaces()[0].Name;
```

but neither of these lists the Generic interface such as ITrendingCafe, ITrendingRestaurant etc.

Is there a way I can get the name of the generic interface name?

Comment: Are you looking for the specialized generic interface or are you looking for the types used to specialize each generic interface?

Comment: I want a list so that i can place the name of it in a class tag on the web page which will then have a corresponding css class for styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the Type's [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method.

If I understand your structure, it will be something like:

```
Type[] typeArguments = fvm.trendItems[4].trendItem.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

foreach (Type tParam in typeArguments)
{
    // Compare the type with the interface you are looking for.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that `ITrendingCafe` is an interface that implements `ITrendingItem`.  I wrote a quick program that takes and displays all of the interfaces that `T` Implements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestConsoleApplication
{
    public interface ITrendingItem
    {
        string ItemName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITrendingCafe : ITrendingItem
    {
        string CafeName { get; set; }
    }


    public class TrendingItem<T> where T : ITrendingItem
    {
        public T trendItem { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cafe : ITrendingCafe
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string CafeName { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new List<TrendingItem<ITrendingItem>> { new TrendingItem<ITrendingItem> { trendItem = new Cafe() } };

            foreach (var trendingItem in test[0].trendItem.GetType().GetInterfaces())
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(trendingItem.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the interface is there.  Just loop through and find the one you need!